How to suppress the password asking popup in Pdftron while editing the document
I have upgraded my Pdftron version from 8.7 to 10.10.1. When I am trying to edit the document using the new version(10.10.1) it is asking for a password. It was not there in my previous version(8.7). How can I edit the document without password. Is there any option available for that in Pdftron/Webviewer

I have already passed the password inside the loadDocument. But still it is asking for password while editing the document
